# No onclick event for jQuery element added after initial page load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

In our rails app, we have a table where each tbody row is a nested field. I want to limit nested fields based on current field count. To do so, I am following [this guide](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/wiki/How-To:-Limit-max-count-of-nested-fields#limit-a-single-nested-model) provided by the nested_form docs.

To better suit our app, I modified the code below.

```
// app/views/users/index.html.haml
:javascript
  $(function() { limitNestedFields('#{@tenant.max_users}'); })

// app/assets/javascripts/limit_nested_fields.js
function limitNestedFields(limitingFactor) {
  var fieldsCount = $('tr.fields').length,
      maxFieldsCount = limitingFactor,
      $addLink = $('.add_nested_fields');
  function toggleAddLink() {
    $addLink.toggle(fieldsCount <= maxFieldsCount)
  }
  $addLink.click(function() {
    console.log("ADDING FIELD");
    if(fieldsCount < limitingFactor){
      fieldsCount += 1;
    }
    toggleAddLink();
  });
  $('.remove_nested_field').click(function() {
    console.log("REMOVING FIELD");
    fieldsCount -= 1;
    toggleAddLink();
  });
  toggleAddLink();
}
```

When inserting console statements, I am able to see that clicking `$addLink` works as expected. When I reach `limitingFactor` number of tbody rows, `$addLink` button disappears. However, I only receive log statements if I click `$('.remove_nested_field')` **if it was present on page load**.

This is important, because say a tenant may only have 10 users, and currently has 6. Say they add 4 rows of nested fields (4 users) BEFORE hitting Update. The "Add User" button (`$addLink`) will toggle hide. If they incorrectly fill in a nested field and wish to delete one (`$('.remove_nested_field')`), then the "Add User" will only appear if they click one of the *original 6 rows before adding*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$('<selector>').click(function() {
```

with

```
$(document).delegate('<selector>', 'click', function() {
```

this should be triggered on elements that were added after this script was run initially.

Explanation:
When you do .click you are adding events on to a known, specific, list of elements. If you add new elements they don't have the event, even if they match that selector.

With .delegate, you're putting an event onto the whole DOM (aka document) saying "when we get a click, see if it's on this selector and if so do this function". So because the selector-checking happens AFTER the click, it includes ones that have been added since.

The function .on has a similar pattern and is supposed to be used instead of delegate with more modern versions of jquery:  http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: I only had to make one change -- make the selector i.fa.fa-remove, because that element was the highest-level part of the underlying link element. Could you post some documentation or reasoning as to why this works, over my previous code?

Comment: BTW if this answer fixed your problem then feel free to mark it correct :)

Comment: I will mark it as correct. Just please add your explanation (comment) to the answer itself. It was very helpful, and is useful if someone does not read the comments.

Comment: done, thanks: you're right about not burying stuff in comments :)

Comment: When I submitted this question, there were others with similar titles. Given your answer, would you suggest a better title for the question? Maybe a less-broad of a scope? Feel free to edit it yourself :-)

Comment: I've changed "selecting..." to "No onclick event..."